# How can I use webapp2 in Google App Engine using Python 2.5?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, webapp2

I want to use [webapp2](http://code.google.com/p/webapp-improved/), which is the default for Python 2.7, under Python 2.5. Is this possible? How?

Comment: Why not just migrate your app to the 2.7 runtime? You'll have to do it at some point anyway.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Webapp2 is part of the Python 2.7 runtime but it's also a library compatible with Python 2.5  that you can [download](http://code.google.com/p/webapp-improved/downloads/list) and use in your project like many other libraries.
Indeed, as noted in the documentation, Webapp2 can be used outside of GAE independently of the App Engine SDK.

To use it in your GAE Python 2.5 project, you don't need any additional download because Webapp2 is  shipped with the GAE SDK and can be imported independently of the Runtime adopted <sup>*</sup>.

Here is a trivial example on how to use Webapp2 in the old Python 2.5 runtime:

**app.yaml**

```
application: testwebapp2
version: 1
runtime: python
api_version: 1

handlers:
- url: .*
  script: main.py
```

**main.py**

```
import webapp2
class HelloWebapp2(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        self.response.write('Hello, webapp2!')

app = webapp2.WSGIApplication([
    ('/', HelloWebapp2),
], debug=True)

def main():
    app.run()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

<sup>* Just be sure to use the latest SDK available</sup>

Comment: This is a great answer. I wish I could upvote it a few times.

Answer (score 0):

yes, webapp2 is part of Python 2.7.

A very good way to use that library with python 2.7 is in this App engine Boilerplate https://github.com/coto/gae-boilerplate

Comment: Right, last person gave you the answer,  I am only giving you another solution.